# how to export data as text file

Tags: export, data, text

I have a list `abc={{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}}}`, where all the x and y are the coordinates.

How to import the coordinates into a text file, in which each line only has one pair of coordinates? Ideally, I want the x and y coordinates separated by a space, but without any brackets or comma.

I tried using the `Export['testing.txt', abc]`, but it ends up with lots of brackets, comma, and all in one line. They are also in scientific notation e.g. `{1.6438124245508942*^-9, 4.264146107953855*^-9}`. I want them to be plain decimal numbers.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure of the best way but here is one method.

As I understand it you don't want scientific notation.

```
abc = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}]*10^-9
```

Convert the list to strings after applying `AccountingForm`.

```
strings = Map[{ToString[AccountingForm[#[[1]]]], 
    ToString[AccountingForm[#[[2]]]]} &, abc]
```

It looks like

```
Grid[strings]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Export strings using "Table"

```
Export["strings.txt", strings, "Table"]
```