# Writing a data file without curly brackets and commas

Tags: export, data

I want to rewrite a data file without curly brackets and commas. Here is a sample of my huge file,

```
{2.3, 2.3, 300.008, 83.517, -17.385}
{2.3, 2.4, 300.003, 71.261, -20.1293}
{2.3, 2.5, 300.002, 60.9547, -23.4817}
{2.3, 2.6, 300.002, 52.2331, -27.3271}
{2.3, 2.7, 300.002, 44.8068, -31.589}
{2.3, 2.8, 300.002, 38.4473, -36.2029}
{2.3, 2.9, 300.002, 32.9726, -41.1137}
```

I want it to be like

```
2.3 2.7 300.002 44.8068  -31.589
```

Help please?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica. Have you had a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123957/how-to-export-data-as-text-file?rq=1) for example. See also the documentation for Exporting text files as this should be able to help you out.